# QWebView reimp. contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent*)

Tags: qt, contextmenu, qwebview

I've reimp. QWebView::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent*) and it takes no effect on right click on the widget.

Here is my code:

```
void ExtendedWebView::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "called";
    m_copyAction->setEnabled(!selectedHtml().isEmpty());
    m_contextMenu->setVisible(true);
    m_contextMenu->exec(event->globalPos());
}
```

When I make right-click on the widget, it takes no effect - no menu is shown. What am I doing wrong?

**UPD**: http://paste.kde.org/640508/ - full code

Comment: Have you made sure that ExtendedWebView::contextMenuPolicy is Qt::DefaultContextMenu ??

Comment: Yup. In constuctor is that call

Comment: Are you also sure the m_contextMenu is not empty? I tried reproducing your code and it works OK, unless m_contextMenu is empty.

Comment: I will give you my full code paste.

Comment: Well, you full code works for me...

Comment: Kubuntu 12.10 & Qt 4.8.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version of Marble's PopupItem where this QWebView is running in does not forward the contextMenuEvent. Change its eventFilter to do that and you'll receive the event.